# Loading properties file while running camel blueprint test

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi, camel-test

I am using `property-placeholder` tag to load a properties as follows:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="myblueprint.test" persistent-id="camel.blueprint"/>
```

While deploying my project on JBOSS Fuse, it will load `camel.blueprint.cfg` from `/etc/` directory of FUSE, and when I deploy project on a fabric profile, it will read from properties file created in profile.

But, when I run [camel blueprint test](http://camel.apache.org/blueprint-testing.html), how can I configure it to load properties file from a particular location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After browsing the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html) for `property-placeholder`, I got the solution. We can set the location for properties file in test case file as follows:

```
@Override
protected String[] loadConfigAdminConfigurationFile() {
    // String[0] = tell Camel the path of the .cfg file to use for OSGi ConfigAdmin in the blueprint XML file
    // String[1] = tell Camel the persistence-id of the cm:property-placeholder in the blueprint XML file
    return new String[]{"src/test/resources/etc/stuff.cfg", "stuff"};
}
```

- Please ensure that, property file is having extension `.cfg`. otherwise it will be ignored.